# Animated Frosted Glass

Tags: ios, swift, blur, gaussian

I understand how I should use the frosted glass blur (Gaussian blur) to blur a view, however I only know how to do it with taking a screenshot.  What if I want to do it with animated/moving elements?  And even more specifically, what if I want to make something like the navigation bar have the frosted glass look?  Any suggestions or resources would be appreciated, thanks! (I can show the code I'm currently using for the static blur upon request) Swift please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a dynamic blurred effect you can use the `UIVisualEffectView` with a `UIBlurEffect`.

**Documentation:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBlurEffect_Ref/index.html